# Simple css nested div not displaying on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a menu to display on hover. I have it working in a simple case, but when I try to add it to the rest of my page, that includes other divs and such, the menu doesn't display.

```css
#main_nav ul, #main_nav:active ul { 
    display: none;
}

#menu-icon:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

#menu-icon {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background: #4C8FEC url(../images/menu.jpg) center;
}

#main_nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/html4.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
        <h1>Main App Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="main_nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Time Entry</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Supervisors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Payroll</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HR</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you're using a descendant selector, and the anchor is nested in a completely different div to your list.

Answer (score 1):

Your  selector  `#menu-icon:hover ul`, is wrong: it will set the style to the **children** `ul` of your `hover`ed element!

To solve this, you should use the sibling selector `~`.
To solve this I capture the `over` event in the `#header` and modify its sibling with the rule `#header:hover ~ #main_nav`.

Remember that, with just these rules, when you move your mouse, from the header to the menu it will disappear again! So I shifted the menu a bit to the top (`15px`) so it intersects the header.

This is my working css:

```css
#main_nav { 
    display: none;
    margin-top:-15px;
}

#main_nav:hover, #header:hover ~ #main_nav {
    display: block;
}

#menu-icon {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background: #4C8FEC url(../images/menu.jpg) center;
}

#main_nav  {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Try it yourself here:http://jsfiddle.net/d8EDS/3/

Comment: While this works, given that @user3507884 is working with a menu it is not really functional because once the user tries to use the menu it disappears again because the user is no longer hovering over #header.

Comment: well, this is embarassing

Comment: You can up-vote these useful answers and put the one that solved the issue as "accepted" by clicking the green "V" in the left.

Comment: clever fix @AntonioRagagnin

Answer (score 0):

if you move your "main_nav" DIV and its UL into the header the above mentioned usability issue is fixed (i.e. the user can actually use the menu) - note that using this fix the "~" for sibling is removed because the element is moved to a position making it a child

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/html4.css">
<style>
#main_nav { 
    display: none;
}

#header:hover  #main_nav{
    display: block;
}

#menu-icon {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background: #4C8FEC url(../images/menu.jpg) center;
}

#main_nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
        <h1>Main App Title</h1>
    <div id="main_nav"
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Time Entry</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Supervisors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Payroll</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HR</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is `#main_nav` now?

Comment: Ssorry, i accidentally removed the `id="main_nav"` when cleaning up my code. It has been fixed above.